# How to import users in Keycloak from Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I have users and groups in Azure Active Directory. I want to import all users from Azure AD into Keycloak.

Anyone from Azure that can help me with the configuration of LDAP with Azure in Keycloak, namely the follow section:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to migrate the users or still use Azure Active Directory as an authentication external "DB"

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151538/how-to-synchronize-microsoft-users-from-azure-into-the-keycloak/66152483#66152483 ?

Comment: @dreamcrash I want to migrate all users from Azure and then I wanted to use Keycloak as an authenticator

Comment: Then you can just used what I have posted on the other question

Comment: Did you had a look ins't that what you want?

Comment: I went through the above documentation. But I didn't get the way for "Configure all the Required Settings accordingly"

Comment: What exactly you do not understand there? you need to configure as you would for any other LDAP active directory, this will depend on your Active Directory

Comment: Maybe I need to talk with our Azure guys about this. I went through all Azure portal for the same but I am unable to configure it. Thanks for the answer