# How to synchronize Microsoft users from Azure into the Keycloak

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-services

We are trying to figure out a way to synchronize users from Azure Account into the Keycloak?

Unfortunately, we could not find a documentation for it

Do you know a proper way to do it ?

I want to use Azure as an external DB that I can use to authenticate my users.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use Azure as an external DB that I can use to authenticate
> my users

For that you can use [Keycloak's User Federation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation) functionality:

> Many companies have existing user databases that hold information
> about users and their passwords or other credentials. In many cases,
> it is just not possible to migrate off of those existing stores to a
> pure Keycloak deployment. **Keycloak can federate existing external user
> databases. By default, we support LDAP and Active Directory, but you
> can also code your own extension for any custom user database using
> our User Storage SPI.**
>
> The way it works is that when a user logs in, Keycloak will look into
> its own internal user store to find the user. If it cannot find it
> there, it will iterate over every User Storage provider you have
> configured for the realm until it finds a match. Data from the
> external store is mapped into a common user model that is consumed by
> the Keycloak runtime.  (..)

In that section of the documentation you have all that you need. Nonetheless, to add the User Federation:

- Go to your Realm;
- Select User Federation;
- Add provider -> ldap;
- Configure all the Required Settings accordingly;
- Save.

Comment: the OP asked specifically to federate users from Azure AD to Keycloak. AFAIK Keycloak accepts LDAP or Kerberos as providers, but Azure AD does support neither of this. So I think while your answer is correct in a general sense, it might mislead readers to think that Azure AD and Keycloak user federation works out-of-the-box.

Comment: @linus Hi thanks for the comment, if you go to User Federation > Ldap and create you can see in the field Vendor the options: "Active Directory", "Red Hat Directory Server", "Tivoli", "Novell eDirectory", and "Other".

Comment: thanks for your reply. It was clear to me that Keycloak does work with Active Directory out of the box. But I read that Azure AD (it's not the same as the "old" AD) does not work well with the user federation process to keycloak. Still happy to hear that I am wrong.